How many unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ can you have, all of which have pairwise dot product less or equal to $0 < c < 1$ in absolute value?
I can't solve this. If $c=0$, then the answer is $n$. If $c=1$, you can have arbitrarily many.
Is there some asymptotic bound as n goes to infinity, as a function of $c$, that's known? How would you prove/derive this?

Does the following post answer your question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24864/almost-orthogonal-vectors

If $c=1$ you can only have $1,$ I think?

Any two unit-norm vector has inner-product at most $1$ (with equality iff the vectors are identical). Therefore, for $c=1$, you can have arbitrarily many

For $c=0$, the answer is not $n$ but $2n$. You can take the vectors in the standard basis and all their negatives.

I edited it. I meant absolute value of the dot product.

Yes @Euclid that looks like it answers my question. thanks.

These unit vectors are points on the unit sphere in ${\mathbb R}^n$, and the condition you are asking says that you want them to be separated by a certain angle -- which at a unit distance equates to a minimal distance. That equates to the sphere packing problem on the surface of the sphere.
